# How do I reference a specific value in a nested NumPy array?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I have a function from an external package that returns a nested group of NumPy arrays. For example, from IPython:

```
In [28]: out = Function()

In [29]: out
Out[29]: 
[[array([ 1.,  1.,  0.,  1.,  0.])],
 [array([ 4.,  4.,  5.,  4.,  5.])],
 [array([ 3.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  1.])],
 [array([ 3.,  6.,  1.,  6.,  4.])],
 [array([ 3.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.])],
 [array([  3.,  17.,  10.,  25.,  23.])],
 [array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])],
 [array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])],
 [array([ 0.,  4.,  2.,  5.,  3.])],
 [array([ 0.,  0.,  2.,  2.,  2.])],
 [array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])],
 [array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])],
 [array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.])],
 [array([  0.,   1.,   6.,  11.,  15.])]]
```

I can assign something like:

```
In [30]: a = out[9]

In [31]: a
Out[31]: [array([ 0.,  0.,  2.,  2.,  2.])]
```

And then finally:

```
In [32]: b = a[0]

In [33]: b[-1]
Out[33]: 2.0
```

To get a specific value that comes out of that array - namely, the last value of the 9th array in the function's output. But I'd really not prefer to make a torrent of variables every time I want to reference something - is there a clean way of referencing a specific interior part of a nested array like this?

Comment: Are you sure this strange list of list of numpy arrays is worth it? You should be able to treat the data as a 2D numpy array for many purposes.

Comment: @Ophion It's part of an external package. If I was implementing it myself? No. But since I don't want to reimplement the thing from scratch, I'm making due for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a strangely shaped object: it's a list of 1-element lists whose element is a 1D numpy array.  So we need three indices:

```
>>> out[9]
[array([ 0.,  0.,  2.,  2.,  2.])]
>>> out[9][0]
array([ 0.,  0.,  2.,  2.,  2.])
>>> out[9][0][-1]
2.0
```

which will also work if we want to modify it:

```
>>> out[9][0][-1] *= 100
>>> out[9][0][-1]
200.0
>>> out[9]
[array([   0.,    0.,    2.,    2.,  200.])]
```

Comment: Yeah - it's an oddly shaped object indeed, and I was having trouble unpacking it in my mind. But the multitude of indices works. Thanks for your help.